# PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant ALTERNATE_WP_CRON

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code

> define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);

in wp-config.php
returns the following error

> PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x98ALTERNATE_WP_CRON\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x98ALTERNATE_WP_CRON\xe2\x80\x99' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /mnt/web220/e3/09/51323409/htdocs/WordPress_01/wp-config.php on line 50

Comment: you have a (hidden) unicode / encoding issue

Comment: what does it mean? where can I edit it (sorry i am very noobie)